# Generate a generic list of a class' variables of a given type in a generic way

Tags: c#, generics

So, I've built a class that has 5 variables, 3 of which are Dictionary<int,string>() and would like to get the data from these 3 dictionaries using a, generic as possible, method. After some research, I came up with this implementation:

```
public static List<K> ClassFieldsOfType<T,K>(T @class, K fieldType) where K : class
{
    List<K> fieldContents = new List<K>();
    List<object> classFields = new List<object>();
    classFields = @class.GetType().GetFields().Select(field =>
       field.GetValue(@class)).ToList();
    foreach (var field in classFields)
    {
        if (field.GetType() == fieldType.GetType())
            fieldContents.Add((K)field);
    }
    return fieldContents;
}
```

But I can't find a way to call my method properly, getting casting errors instead. My current attempt to do so is this:

```
void SetKitPiecesCount(KitSet kitSet)
{
    var composition = kitSet.kitInternalData.jerseyComposition; // One of the dictionaries Dictionary<int,string>
    var compositionDataType = composition.GetType();    //get the Dictionary<int,string> type
    kitPiecesComposition = ClassUtilities.ClassFieldsOfType(
        kitSet.kitInternalData, compositionDataType);   //This is the error line, where I  call the method,
                                                        //setting its return in a List<Dictionary<int,string>> type
}
```

Error message using the approach above:

[image]

While the error is simple, I couldn't find a way to solve my problem. Already tried to change "where K : class" for "where K : Type" and "where K : IDictionary" with no luck. Also, tried to change the way the method call is made, declaring the types explicitly between <> for example, but then another error appeared...

Does anyone know how can I achieve this? Maybe I'm completely wrong here, despite liking to build things using a generic approach, I always have some trouble trying to implement generic stuff the way I need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fieldType` parameter should either be of type `Type` (and generic parameter `K` should be removed) or just removed depending on situation. If you know desired type at the compile time you can start from something like this:

```cs
public static List<K> ClassFieldsOfType<K>(object @class) where K : class
{
    var result = @class.GetType()
        .GetFields()
        .Where(fi => fi.FieldType == typeof(K))
        .Select(field => (K) field.GetValue(@class))
        .ToList();

    return result;
}
```

And usage like that:

```cs
ClassFieldsOfType<Dictionary<int, string>>(someObject)
```